# How to change google account without wiping?

Tags: nexus-one, google-account, factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How-to unlink the main Google account from android device without a factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-to-unlink-the-main-google-account-from-android-device-without-a-factory-rese)

I'd like to change the google account an unrooted Nexus One is linked to without wiping. If I try to remove the current account it says it can't do it without a factory reset...

Comment: @eldarerathis: definitely a dupe

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you can't change the primary account without a wipe.

However, you can use Titanium Backup to back up your apps and settings so that putting your phone's environment back together after is a snap.

Comment: Incorrect, Titanium Backup does pretty much nothing useful if you're not rooted, that's the problem. It certainly doesn't backup application data, which is the whole problem.

Comment: Yes, you have to be rooted but that should not be a problem with the Nexus One.  And it most certainly does back up application data; I've used it to do just that many times.

Comment: currently you can't get root without wiping

Comment: Just did a quick search. It seems you can [get root on the Nexus One](http://chensun.net/android-development/root-nexus-one-with-android-2-3-3-gingerbread/8/) just by adding a few binaries (su, fastboot, recovery)

Comment: Unfortunately, that post is quite probably outdated: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/19432/2665

Comment: It's from March 2001, and says it works for Gingerbread.  What version of Android are you running on the N1?  Also, unlocking the bootloader might indeed wipe your data, which would suck.  You can at least reload you app list easily though with AppBrain.